# ipad orientation problem with webview

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, orientation

I'm creating ipad application. It has just 2 views.
One view has few buttons. On click of a button it will open another view. This view has a webview which shows PDF file. I'm using the following code to show the PDF

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mypdf" ofType:@"pdf"];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]]];
```

}

Now the problem is that, when I change the orientation, whole view is rotating, but the pdf is being disturbed and not rendering properly. how can I avoid this?

As the PDF is having 250 pages, reloading the whole PDF on willRotateToInterfaceOrientation and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation will delay the display.

How to avoid this situation.

Comment: could you please elaborate on "disturbed and not rendering properly"?

Comment: I also have just discovered this effect, for me it renders half of each (loaded and not necessarily all) pages at a consistent y offset. The half that is rendered wrongly alternates with each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has to be a way a better to avoid/fix this, for now i just read the y scroll position with:

```
int scrollPosition = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.pageYOffset"] intValue];
```

Then reloaded the document in:

```
(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;
```

and then set the scroll position again with:

`[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"scrollTo(0,%d)",scrollPosition];`